# Configuring a data grid filter based on a search string (KendoUI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm new to using KendoUI Builder and I'm having trouble filtering a grid's data based off of a search string. Every time I enter data into the input component, no filtering occurs at all. The very unusual part is that this was working prior and I do not have the faintest clue as to what could have caused a total loss in functionality.

the following input is tagged for the searchModel:

```html
<input type="text" id="inputName" class="k-textbox k-input" placeholder="Search by Last Name" ng-model="vm.searchModel"/>
```

And the following code is located in the controller.public.js file for the onShow() method:

```html
onShow($scope) 
    {
        console.log('Show');

        this.$scope.$watch(

                     () => {return this.searchModel;},

                     (searchVal) => 
                     {

                    let searchFilter = {};

                    if (searchVal) 
                    {
                        searchFilter = 
                        {
                             logic: "or",
                             filters: [
                             {field: "name", operator:"begins with", value: searchVal}
                            ]
                        };
                        
                    }
                    this.$ds.filter(searchFilter);
                    });
    }

}
```

If any more context is required please let me know and I will do what I can. All help and suggestions are greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: i think your filter operator is wrong. should be "startswith"

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.operator

Comment: Whoops! Yes you are correct, I've made the change to "startswith" and unfortunately still no change in functionality.